# How to remove the Pagination in Ultimate WP Query Search Filter plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want display all the search result without pagination , so please guide me how to remove the pagination in `Wordpress Ultimate WP Query Search` Filter Plugin .

Plugin URL : https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-wp-query-search-filter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

change result per page with **-1**

Comment: -1 value not allowing to add  in the Result per page field , its only allowing numerical numbers. Is there any way to remove the pagination through coding ?

Comment: in your misc.php file...    its on this url ultimate-wp-query-search-filter\admin\fields\misc.php          in l\this line  $html.= '<input type="text" id="numberpost" name="uwpname[rel][0][resultc]" value="'.$result.'" size="2"/><br>';     just put value="-1"